# Problem in having space in the middle of WiFi name for see password in cmd

Tags: cmd, wifi

I get the passwords that I forgot but are on the Windows with the code in `cmd`.

My code is:

```
netsh wlan show profile Namewifi key=clear
```

After that, I see the password, but it does not accept a WiFi name that has space in the middle, and only recognizes the first part of the name.

```
netsh wlan show profile poco x3 key=clear
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the WiFi name in double quotation marks:

```
netsh wlan show profile "poco x3" key=clear
```